# Phenomenon regarding square of any integer.....

Tags: number-theory

There is a phenomenon regarding squares of integers which i observed today.

$n^2 = \sum_1^n^-^1 + \sum_1^n $

I am a computer science graduate and i never heard about this phenomenon till date.
Is it already found by someone in history? Why this phenomenon occurs?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything inside your sums.

Comment: He might mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i= (n-1)n/2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i = n(n+1)/2$, added to $n^2$,

Comment: Gauss was famous for recognizing the individual sums at age 7, by adding $1 \ldots 100$ using pairs giving $101$ each.

Comment: Please learn how to write $\LaTeX$ when you're going to use it. There are numerous resources available at the tip of your fingertips thanks to the internet. If you fail to discover how to write in LaTeX, at least provide the correct equations and formulas and expressions using other means, i.e. plain language or normal ascii. At any rate, look up "triangular numbers." @mvw The details of [this anecdote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes) are uncertain. I have never seen the age specified, let alone so low at three.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for why, look at:
$$
\begin{matrix}
++++++++ \\
+++++++- \\
++++++-- \\
+++++--- \\
++++---- \\
+++----- \\
++------ \\
+------- 
\end{matrix}
$$
The one sum counts the pluses, the other sum counts the minuses.

Comment: Nice answer! Much more interesting than the dull manipulation me and $2$ others came up with.

Comment: Thanks. But I think there is value in both approaches.

Comment: I might have posted this drawing a while ago (with black/white squares for pluses/minuses). By far the most intuitive explanation, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple step behind a standard formula:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i + \sum_{i=1}^n i = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i +n = 
2\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n = n^2-n+n = n^2$$

Answer (score 1):

I presume the equation you wanted to write is $$n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i + \sum_{i=1}^ni$$

which is easily shown using the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$which gives you 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i + \sum_{i=1}^ni = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} +\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n}{2}(n-1+n+1) = \frac{n}{2}\cdot2n = n^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a (very) well-known result.
Here is a picture for $n=3$.

$\begin{array}{cccc} x&x&x& \\ x&x&&x \\x&&x&x \end{array}$